# xpages how to hide element (field) using java script

Tags: javascript, css, field, hide, xpages

in xpages, as i know that only editable field able to get value (retrieve) from context. 
My question: how hide field using css or java script in xpages so i can still get value from context?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `style="display:none"` as inputText control's property. This will render the control but will hide it. You can assign values on client side to this control.

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    style="display:none"
    value="#{...}">
</xp:inputText>
```

In client side JavaScript you can hide an inputText control with

```
document.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").style.display = 'none'
```

but this is only necessary if you want to show it first and hide it later by a e.g. button click.

Comment: Could you please more detail how put the style display = none? thank you

Comment: Added an example for `style="display:none"` usage.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may (depending on requirements) be to use the Hidden Input control. You may need to click the *Other...* button in the Controls Palette or customise the palette to access it. The palette options can be customised by right-clicking in the Controls Palette and selecting *Customize Palette...*

Comment: Could you please more detail step to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answer. This question has solved, i just import CSS from domino : \data\domino\java\xsp\theme\oneuiv2.1
Then i selected the field and chosen field hidden
Done, now the field value able to transfer from context

Thanks All :)